# Laptop won't suspend on 16.04 (Kernel 4.4.8)

Tags: suspend, power-management, acpi

So I had Kubuntu 16.04 which had been upgraded from 15.10.  Always worked fine and slept when I closed the lid.  I installed Ubuntu (switched from Kubuntu) (clean install, formatted root partition) 16.04 and now my laptop won't sleep when I close the lid or when I select Suspend from the power menu.

I tried `echo mem > /sys/power/state` as root but it only shuts off my screen, everything else stays on, and I can't get the screen to come back on.

I have an HP DV7 Laptop with i7, dual switchable graphics (Intel/AMD Radeon HD 7960M XT).  I installed Ubuntu with no third-party drivers, just stock from USB.  Also to note that booting into a live session from the USB still doesn't allow suspend.

My system has 2 hard drives laid out like so:

```
SDA (GRUB boot loader here) Windows 10    
SDB1 (NTFS) Storage drive for both OS'es    
SDB3 /home (ext4)    
SDB5 swap    
SDB6 / (root, ext4)
```

Windows 10 still works fine. Boots into Ubuntu fine, everything works except suspend.

**UPDATE** : I'm still at a loss here. I updated my kernel to 4.4.8 but this didn't fix it.

I removed the `#` from `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` in the `logind.conf` and that didn't work.

I ran `acpi_listen` in the terminal, closed and opened the lid, and it is detecting lid closed and lid opened.

Here is the output of acpi_listen:

```
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open
```

Still not sure why it's not working...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out so I'm posting an answer for those who are stuck like me.

Since pm-suspend worked perfectly for me, I edited this file:

**/etc/default/acpi-support**

Looked for this line:

```
SUSPEND_METHODS="dbus-pm dbus-hal pm-utils"
```

Changed it to this:

```
SUSPEND_METHODS="pm-utils"
```

Now it works like it should!

Answer (score 1):

This could solve your problem. I once had this problem and i solved it using this method:

Open a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>

Open `logind.conf` by running command

`sudo vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf`

and remove the `#` before `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`. You can also change the option `suspend` to `hibernate` or `poweroff`

Fix from [Launchpad Bug #863834, comment #30](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/863834#30):

1. Open a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
2. `sudo mkdir /etc/acpi/local`
3. `sudo vim /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post`
4. Copy this short script:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
    then
        /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
    fi
   ```

   ... and paste it into vim by typing: <kbd>"+p</kbd>
5. Save by typing <kbd>ZZ</kbd> (in capitals)
6. `sudo chmod 755 /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post` (so it works even when power management is handled under the logged-in user instead of root)

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: No this doesn't work.  But, if I do "sudo pm-suspend", the laptop does go to sleep, and wakes up fine.  But closing the lid still does nothing.